# Passing html as a template variable django

Tags: html, django, templates

I am passing some html to my template like this `passDict["problemText"] = <p> Some html</p>
return render(response,'main/base.html',passDict)`.  And then displaying `{{problemText}}` in my html file.I get `<p> Some html</p>` as my text and not `Some html` in a paragraph like i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be marked as safe.

Use the `safe` filter.

```html
{{ problemText|safe }}
```

Or use the `mark_safe()` method.

```py
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

problemText = mark_safe("<p>Some html</p>")
```

Read the documentation on the [safe filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) and [`mark_safe()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe).